# Problem on Proxying API Requests from react

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy

My backend is developed with  .NET and hosted in a **local docker container** on `localhost:8080`, and the client side is created with CRA.

In **package.json** file for my react app , i added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` but this is not working and  It is not making any call to the `8080`, react is still considering it's own port `3000` (but it works fine when I put `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/session")`).

Please help me solve this problem, I tried several suggestions on the forums(clear cache, re-configure webpack-dev,...) but nothing worked for me.